# Scapy python script causing too many open files on mac

Tags: python, scapy

Every time I use scapy's send() function it seems to open/use/access a /dev/bpf device and never seems to release them until i exit my script. I don't fully understand the /dev/bpf other than it standing for Berkley packet filter, but the problem is after it reaches the limit on my machine of what seems to be /dev/bpf255 my script crashes do to "too many open files".

Code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import threading

q = 0

def printit():
    global q
    q += 1
    print(q)
    threading.Timer(1.0, printit).start()
    data= "Test"
    a = IP(dst="255.255.255.255")/UDP(dport=3520)/data
    send(a)

printit()
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 73, in sndrcv
    rdpipe,wrpipe = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I am assuming it is being caused by the /dev/bpf devices because when I run:

```
lsof |grep {script pid}
```

I see what seems to be one more /dev/bpf opened for each packet that is sent.

For example my grep result is:

```
Python    39601             user   91w      CHR              23,44        0t107   15141 /dev/bpf44
```

They are never released. I can't seem to figure out how to clean this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Could you give us the code that you have(not just two lines), what you're expecting, and what you're seeing instead?

Comment: My apologies, I have added code that will cause this error and the error itself being caused.

Comment: You have defined a recursive function with no stop condition. Try limiting the number of spawned threads.